# FosRestBundle Route generation with CamelCase class

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I have a slight Problem with on of my Controllers.

The Entity the api is for is called: `MyEntity` so naturally the controller is called: `MyEntityController`

If I now define an action: `public function getMyEntity($id)`
the route that is generated is called: `/mys/:id/entitys`

How do I define the controller in a way that the route becomes `/my-entities/:id` ?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you define the route manually the way you want?:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/7-manual-route-definition.html